# Removing 1 hour with strtotime PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm trying to remove 1 hour with `strtotime()` without success.

value of `$taskentry['date_start']` : 2017-11-02 02:19:59

value of `$taskentry['date_end']` : 2017-11-02 02:32:06

```
<?php 
     $cut = 3600;
     $date_start = strtotime($taskentry['date_start']);
     $date_end =  strtotime($taskentry['date_end']);
     $total = ($date_end - $date_start) - $cut; 
         if($total < 0){
         echo '0';
         }else{
         echo date("H:i:s", $total);
         }?>
```

The result should return `12:07` but it returns 0. I have also tried with

```
$cut = strtotime('-60min') and $cut = strtotime('-1 hour');
```

Return same result.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: `$total = ($date_end - $date_start);` will return `12:07`

Comment: stop using the legacy `strtotime` you should always use the DateTime class

Answer (score 0):

```
if($total > 0)
```

change the lesser than symbol to greater than symbol

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
The time difference between start and end is less than one hour.
Then you subtract one hour meaning it's a negative number.
Then you say if it's negative output "0".

The code does exactly what it's supposed to.
See here with more than one hour difference:

```
$cut = 3600;
$date_start = strtotime("2017-11-02 02:19:59");
$date_end =  strtotime("2017-11-02 03:32:06");
$total = ($date_end - $date_start) - $cut; 

 if($total < 0){
     echo '0';
 }else{
     echo date("H:i:s", $total);
 }
```

Output:

```
01:12:07
```

https://3v4l.org/QRLdK

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the value of `$taskentry['date_end']` 
 is `2017-11-02 02:32:06` not `2017-11-02 03:32:06`. When you change the value, you will see the problem I'm talking about and that's why I remove 1hour because `strtotime()` adds 1 when it's not supposed to.

Comment: I see what you mean but there are still minutes left, you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Sollution

```
<?php

$time="10:09";
$time = date('H:i', strtotime($time.'-1 hour'));
echo $time;

?>
```

Try [Demo](https://3v4l.org/8rQhp) Here